# get an HTML element

Tags: jquery, selector

given an html element

```
<div id="someElement><p>This is an elements contents</p></div>
```

How can I inject this entire element into a document?

*to clarify*:

I'd like to inject the entire element "div#someElement" into another container.

```
<div id="someContainer"></div>
<div id="someElement"><p>Example Content</p></div>

$("#someContainer").html($("#someElement").html());
```

yields...

```
<div id="someContainer"><p>Example Content</p></div>
```

I'd like it to yield this...

```
<div id="someContainer"><div id="someElement"><p>Example Content</p></div></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`.appendTo(selector)`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/), like this:

```
$("#someElement").appendTo("#someContainer");
```

This will take the element and move it to be a child of `#someContainer`. Since you have IDs here, I'm assuming there can be only one of each, if that isn't the case, you may need to use a slightly different usage, e.g. [`.appendTo(element)`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/).  This is one of [a few insertion methods available](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/dom-insertion-inside/).